# ASP.NET MVC5: No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am encountering an error in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application using autofac v3.5.0, Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator v3.2.0,  Autofac.Mvc5 v3.3.2 all with targetframework net45 :

`No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.`

when trying to convert the following Rhino-Security windsor mapping:

```
WindsorServiceLocator windsorServiceLocator = new WindsorServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => windsorServiceLocator);

    container.Register(
            Component.For<IAuthorizationService>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationService>()
                .Lifestyle.Is(Lifestyle.Transient),
            Component.For<IAuthorizationRepository>()
                .ImplementedBy<AuthorizationRepository>()
                .Lifestyle.Is(Lifestyle.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsBuilderService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsBuilderService>()
                .Lifestyle.Is(Lifestyle.Transient),
            Component.For<IPermissionsService>()
                .ImplementedBy<PermissionsService>()
                .Lifestyle.Is(Lifestyle.Transient)
            );
```

to an autofac mapping. The first 4 mappings work without any issue but the last one causes the above error. I have traced the first instance of where the error occurs this line: 
https://github.com/hibernating-rhinos/rhino-security/blob/master/Rhino.Security/Security.cs#L34

```
builder.RegisterType<AuthorizationService>().As<IAuthorizationService>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<AuthorizationRepository>().As<IAuthorizationRepository>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<PermissionsBuilderService>().As<IPermissionsBuilderService>().InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterType<PermissionsService>().As<IPermissionsService>().InstancePerDependency();

// Everything works except this
builder.RegisterType<OrganizationInformationExtractor>().As<IEntityInformationExtractor<Organization>>().InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: How are you resolving the dependencies? Like the error suggests _"this generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.)"_ 
I'm suspecting one of the dependencies in `OrganizationInformationExtractor` is registered InstanancePerRequest

Comment: I've ran into this issue before when I had built a generic Autofac module and I was using it within an ASP.NET application. Some of the components were registered as InstancePerRequest. But when I tried reusing the component for testing, it was failing because the resolve did not from an ASP.NET context

Answer (score 1):

Check all the parameters that OrganizationInformationExtractor needs. One of those parameters is either not registered in autofac or it is nor registered as InstancePerDependency. This worked for me.

Comment: This helped figuring out the problem in my case where I had a SingeInstance class as a dependency to the class I wanted to use